# Tensor equality implies similar decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

Let $V$ and $W$ be two finite-dimensional, (real) vector spaces, and $T \in V\otimes W$ a tensor that has two different forms:
$$T = \sum_{i=1}^n v_i \otimes w_i = \sum_{j=1}^m x_j \otimes y_j,$$
where $v_i, x_j \in V$ and $w_i, y_j \in W$. I am trying to understand whether there exists some sort of relationship between $v_i, x_j$ and $w_i, y_j$. Specifically, I wonder whether there always exist coefficients $a_{ik}, b_{i\ell}\in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$ v_i = \sum_k a_{ik} x_k, \text{ and } w_i = \sum_\ell b_{i\ell} y_{\ell} \quad ? $$

My thought was that due to the linearity of the tensor product, i.e., $(a+b)\otimes c = a\otimes c + b\otimes c$, a tensor can be decomposed into "simpler" parts, and perhaps this goes the other way around.
I get the feeling that this might be wrong, but failed to find a counter-example. Can anyone smarter than me find one? (or indicate to me how one could perhaps prove the statement)

Comment: Quick comment in passing: your *specific* claim is false even for decomposable tensors. If $v\ne 0$ but $w,x=0$, then $v\otimes w=0=x\otimes y$ for any $y$ but $v\ne\alpha x$.

Comment: Duh, of course, how could I not see that... thanks a lot for your help!